# Generic function to return list of objects using ISession's CreateCritieria function in nHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I could able to create a list of objects by doing like this:

```
using (var session = sessionFactory.OpenSession()) {              
    ICriteria criteria = session.CreateCriteria<Foo>();
    IList<Foo> Foo = criteria.List<Foo>();
}
```

where Foo is my class.

I wish to write a generic function to return list of object depending on the input Type as shown below:

```
public IList<T> GetObjList <T> (T obj)
{
    IList<T> list;
    try {
        var sessionFactory = CreateSessionFactory();
        if (sessionFactory == null)
            return null;
        using (var session = sessionFactory.OpenSession()) {
            ICriteria criteria = session.CreateCriteria<T>(); //Error
            list = criteria.List<T>();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        return null;
    }
    return list;
}
```

I'm getting the following compiler error in the line ICriteria criteria = session.CreateCriteria()

```
The type 'T' must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'NHibernate.ISession.CreateCriteria<T>()'
```

Please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generic type parameters can be further **[constrained](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx)** to limit what can be provided as such parameter. What your error message says, is that `NHibernate.ISession.CreateCriteria<T>()` requires its type parameter to be constrained to *reference type*. Since your method doesn't define any constraint at all, C# compiler has no clue whether `T` is a valid type parameter for `CreateCriteria<T>`.

If we take a closer look at NHibernate source code, we indeed can notice that `ISession.CreateCriteria<T>` is declared as follows:

```
public ICriteria CreateCriteria<T>() where T : class
```

As a result, you need the same constraint on your method in order for type parameter passed to it to play nicely with `CreateCriteria` call. Simply change it to:

```
public IList<T> GetObjList<T>(T obj)
    where T : class
{
    /* ... */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
public IList<T> GetObjList <T> (T obj) where T : class
{
    // body doesn't change
}
```

This restricts the type parameter 'T' to be a 'class' - this means that this method will not accept a value type as 'T'.